# Submitting form through iframe: Rails 4 InvalidAuthenticityToken in Chrome, Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, iframe

I have a form on a page which other people can embed through an iframe on their sites. When submitting that form I get an `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error, in Safari and also Chrome (with third-party cookies turned off) but not in Firefox.

My understanding was that I don't have to rely on third-party cookies being activated if I've got this in my header:

```
<head>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

But apparently that's not true...?

And I'm even seeing the token in my server log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=> "2ig3BPn9...
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html):

> Controller actions are protected from Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks by including a token in the rendered HTML for your application. This token is stored as a random string in the session, to which an attacker does not have access. When a request reaches your application, Rails verifies the received token with the token in the session.

So even if you embed the token with `csrf_meta_tags` you still need it also in the session (i.e. in the cookie). That's why with disabled third-party cookies it doesn't work in the iframe.

Comment: Hi, we have the exact same problem but I don't completely understand your answer. What does it mean with disabled third party cookie? I have cookie enabled, the page loads 3 iframes with a from from our domain and those fail randomly. Checked all iframes they all have the same session id.

Answer (score 0):

into form insert:

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>"/>
```

Ex:

```
    <form name="as" target="open_here" method="get" action="material">
    <input type="hidden" name="materialid" value="56"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit open_here" />
</form>
```

or

```
<form name="unit" target="open_here" method="get" action="/redmine/issues_materials/material" >
    <input type="hidden" id="material_id" name="materialid" value="" /><!-- valo value e inputado pelo script 2 document.getElementById('material_id').value = materialid; -->
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>"/> <!-- para funcionar tem que enviar essa chave junto-->
    <input id="idunit" type="submit" value="open here submit" style="display: none;"/>
</form>

<iframe id="open_here" name="open_here" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="60" height="80"></iframe>
```